# For loop to divide a large data frame (30columns) into several smaller data frames (with 3 columns)

Tags: r, loops, select

first time writing a question here so please don't be too harsh. I have a large data.frame called merged with a "Time" column, a "Well" column and 28 columns where each column stores data from measurements of a plate (so 28 plates)[df called merged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZR6G.png).  Now I want to create a "for loop" that creates new dfs with the columns "Time", "Well" and the measurements of a plate starting with plate 1 or column 3 up until the last plate (28 or column 30).
The problem is, I have no idea how I can adjust the name of the new df in the loop so it creates 28 different new dfs with the information of only 1 plate instead of just overwriting the new df and storing only the information of the last plate. [beginner loop function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tidjD.png).
if you need more information, feel free to ask and I will try to deliver the information to the best of my ability.

Thank you all in advance!

Roger

Comment: @ Roger welcome to Stack Overflow - this is an amazingly helpful site. Please don’t use images of data or code as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You’re more likely to get a positive response if your question is reproducible. [See Stack Overflow question guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You probabaly want to convert your data to a long format, an then (if needed) split it up. See here for the first step: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/6356278.. also, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6356278

Comment: First aside - avoid unclear names like *merged*. Assign names by data type and content: e.g., `plate_msmts_df`. Second aside - [avoid having a bunch of data.frames not in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/1422451).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cooked up example. I begin by creating a data.frame that is similar to your data. Then I convert from wide format to long, using the `tidyr` package. (There are other ways to do this).

With the long format, it's then easy to select out the data you want by Plate identifier.

```
#----------------------
# Cook up a data.frame
#----------------------
# 30 sequential dates
dates = seq.Date(as.Date("2022-03-01"), as.Date("2022-03-30"), 1)
# 50 wells 
wells <- lapply(LETTERS[1:5], function(l) {paste0(l, seq(1, 10))})
wells <- unlist(wells)
# Create a data.frame
wells_data <- data.frame(expand.grid(dates, wells))
names(wells_data) <- c("Dates", "Wells")

# 30 columns of artificial data
for (i in 1:30) {
  new_data <- data.frame(runif(1:nrow(wells_data)))
  names(new_data) <- paste0("Plate", i)
  wells_data <- cbind(wells_data, new_data)
}
head(wells_data)
           Dates Wells     Plate1    Plate2    Plate3     Plate4     Plate5
1 2022-03-01    A1 0.20418463 0.5932133 0.7070428 0.04231371 0.25872767
2 2022-03-02    A1 0.95218240 0.1114270 0.3763757 0.22992064 0.05632674
3 2022-03-03    A1 0.07162576 0.9902931 0.1437405 0.40102327 0.56432590
4 2022-03-04    A1 0.17148644 0.1849485 0.2062618 0.45908182 0.44657831
5 2022-03-05    A1 0.11334931 0.4820294 0.1663636 0.87436576 0.60177308
6 2022-03-06    A1 0.13949741 0.7862085 0.6162253 0.50698110 0.75309069
      Plate6     Plate7      Plate8    Plate9    Plate10    Plate11   Plate12
1 0.77206623 0.45816279 0.002027475 0.3821823 0.30170925 0.08730046 0.7638708
2 0.31140577 0.39479768 0.919386005 0.2369556 0.33105790 0.86560846 0.9464049
3 0.36804632 0.30644346 0.782938605 0.3723977 0.21561693 0.14770805 0.7371391
4 0.07265802 0.68454399 0.916244462 0.7688442 0.36590464 0.42293563 0.8448824
5 0.59587190 0.78073586 0.338200076 0.3895508 0.61586528 0.47494553 0.8315232
6 0.41189998 0.06666752 0.721342234 0.5130501 0.06648771 0.61675408 0.9384815
# ...more columns...

#----------------------
# Now convert from wide to long
# and split by plate identifier
#----------------------
library(tidyr)
wells_data <- pivot_longer(wells_data,
                           cols=(3:ncol(wells_data)),
                           names_to="Plate",
                           values_to="measurement")
head(wells_data)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  Dates      Wells Plate  measurement
  <date>     <fct> <chr>        <dbl>
1 2022-03-01 A1    Plate1      0.204 
2 2022-03-01 A1    Plate2      0.593 
3 2022-03-01 A1    Plate3      0.707 
4 2022-03-01 A1    Plate4      0.0423
5 2022-03-01 A1    Plate5      0.259 
6 2022-03-01 A1    Plate6      0.772 

# Now it's easy to select out each Plate:
plates = unique(wells_data$Plate)
lapply(plates, function(p) {
         subset = wells_data[wells_data$Plate == p,]
         # Do whatever you want with this subset
         print(paste("Mean for Plate", p, ":",
                    mean(subset$measurement)))
         
})
```

Hope this might help to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid flooding your global environment with many structurally similar, separate data frames. Consider building a *single* list of many related elements using `lapply` or `sapply` (for names) to build a list of subset data frames. As shown below, you lose no functionality of `data.frame`s if saved in a larger list:

```r
# RETRIEVE ALL V-STARTING COLUMN NAMES
v_cols <- colnames(merged_df)[grep("^V", colnames(merged_df))]

# NAMED LIST OF PLATE SUBSETTED DATA FRAMES
plate_measurements_list <- sapply(
    v_cols, 
    function(i) merged_df[,c("Time", "Well", col)],
    simplify = FALSE
)


# ACCESS AND USE EACH DATA FRAME
head(plate_measurements_list$V1)
tail(plate_measurements_list$V2)
summary(plate_measurements_list$V3)
...
str(plate_measurements_list$V28)
```